# Including new line in a set of REGEXP character values

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to include new line in a set of REGEXP that are whitelisted for this set?

I've been trying to test this everywhere inside this set but my output is always **invalid**

**New line**

```
\r\n
```

**Code**

```
DECLARE
  l_value varchar2(4000) := 'Stack

Overflow';
BEGIN
  IF REGEXP_LIKE(l_value,'^[a-zA-Z0-9$"/\?!%.,:;’\r\n()-]*$') THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('valid');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('invalid');  
  END IF;
END;
/
```

**Output should be**

```
Valid
```

Any inputs will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match newlines in your regexp, you need to add the `'m'` option. [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19):

> 'm' treats the source string as multiple lines. Oracle interprets ^ and $ as the start and end, respectively, of any line anywhere in the source string, rather than only at the start or end of the entire source string. If you omit this parameter, then Oracle treats the source string as a single line.

So:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(l_value,'^[a-zA-Z0-9$"/\?!%.,:;’\r\n()-]*$', 'm')
```

Edit: You might want to use REGEXP_SUBSTR to debug your regular expressions and see what they're matching. In this case, this:

```
select regexp_substr('Stack
Overflow ++', '^[a-zA-Z0-9$"/\?!%.,:;’\r\n()-]*$', 1, 1, 'm')
from dual;
```

Matches `Stack`, because the `$` matches the first end of a line that it finds. (Regexps are "greedy")

It sounds like you want to find strings which ONLY contain whitelisted values. But this regexp matches strings which contain whitelisted values between the start and end of SOME lines.

Instead, I think you want something like this:

```
NOT REGEXP_LIKE(l_value,'[^a-zA-Z0-9$"/\?!%.,:;’()[:space:]-]')
```

Which matches strings which only contain the whitelisted characters. Note that `\r` and `\n` are not valid Oracle character specifications, so I'm using the `[:space:]` character class to match them (as well as any other whitespace).

Comment: Thanks but when I tried to change input into 
  
```l_value varchar2(4000) := 'Stack
  
Overflow ++' ```
  
The output is valid but it should be **invalid** because + sign or any other special characters that are not in the set.

Comment: I see, you want something different. Updated my answer.